# Unable to display an API data using map function on Material UI tabs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, map-function, react-tabs

I'm new to this programming world. Can anyone please help me on this.

I have implemented Material UI's tabs successfully by hard-coding the content, but when I tried to make my hard coded tabs with a .map function to populate the content from a data source (json), it no longer works. The tab displays nothing.

Here are the codes,

Planet component:

```
import React from 'react';

function Planet(props) {

    return (
        <ul>
            <li>{props.name}</li>
        </ul>
    );
}

export default Planet;
```

Planets component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import Planet from './Planet';

function Planets(props) {

    const [planets, setPlanets] = useState([]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        getPlanets();
    }, []);

    const getPlanets = async () => {
        const response = await fetch("https://assignment-machstatz.herokuapp.com/planet");
        const data = await response.json();
        setPlanets(data); 
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {planets.map((planet, index) => {
                return (
                <Planet key={index} name={planet.name} />
                );
        })} 
        </div>
    );

}

export default Planets;
```

App component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { AppBar, Tabs, Tab } from '@material-ui/core';
import Planet from './Planet';
import Favplanets from './Favplanets';

function App() {

    const [selectedTab, setSelectedTab] = useState(0);

    function handleChange (event, newValue) {
        setSelectedTab(newValue);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <AppBar position="static">
            <Tabs value={selectedTab} onChange={handleChange} >
            <Tab label="Planets" />
            <Tab label="Favourite Planets" />
            </Tabs>
        </AppBar>
        {selectedTab === 0 && <Planet />}
        {selectedTab === 1 && <Favplanets />}
        </>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried checking planets length before mapping?

Comment: yes. the length of planets array is 11.

Comment: I mean have tried doing this: planet.length ? planets.map(....) : null

Instead of  mapping directly

Comment: No. I haven't. Thanks, I will try that.

Comment: In App.js component you're importing ./Planet, and rendering  {selectedTab === 0 && <Planet />}, I think it should be <Planets /> component ? can you verify

Comment: ya, I'm rendering <Planet /> as to capture the data that I'm passing from <Planets /> using props. I'm trying to display the data from <Planets /> as list items on <Planet />.

Comment: It will never work actually because inside  App.js component you're importing ./Planet, and rendering {selectedTab === 0 && <Planet />} .This Planet is getting data from Planets,and since you havent called Planets ever you will never get the data.

Comment: Inside Planet component it needs props like `name` ,and when you are calling it from App.js you are not passing any name props to it so it will never display anything.

Comment: thanks. I tried fetching the API data from <Planet /> and mapping the data into the same component itself. It worked. Thanks for guiding me.